# Request to https server with self-signed certificate fails in React-Native android

Tags: android, react-native, https, self-signed

First of all I have to say I'm fairly new to react-native and android development in general (although fluent in react and js).

I have an API server (written with express) which is served over https. Since the system is gonna be used internally (it is an internal service for our company) I am using my own CA and a set of self-signed certificates for all parts of it (the whole system is comprised of several servers talking to each other and serving different things). And every thing is working fine. except for the android part!

I have an android app (react-native) which should send some stuff to one of these servers (the one that has a global static IP).

First I tried to do what I would normally do in js. I used `fetch`. But it failed with error:

```
[TypeError: Network request failed]
```

I suspected that the HTTPS and the whole self-signed certificate situation might be the culprit, so I tested it with a plain HTTP endpoint and it worked.

I thought maybe I need to install my CA on the phone, and I did. But to no avail.

After some search, I stumbled upon something about a new change in android which it doesn't trust user's installed CAs by default, and they suggested to add

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

to the manifest file, and this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

in `res/xml` directory.

I did all this, but it didn't work.

So I'm stuck, and any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I don't know Java, but if you have a solution involving some native code, I can manage it if you provide extensive explanations :D

Answer (score -1):

I use `react-native-ssl-pinning`.

Link: https://github.com/MaxToyberman/react-native-ssl-pinning

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31108542)